# With TLS 1.3 is it possible to conduct the handshake on a separate device from where the main channel is?

Tags: tls

With TLS 1.3 a PSK is established along with main secrets for the encrypted channel.

Can this mechanism be employed to allow client authentication to occur on one device (say a mobile device), which would then transfer those secrets over a separate secure channel to another device (say a desktop app), which would then act as the mobile client in TLS 1.3 communications with a server?

The idea is to (ab)use the TLS 1.3 protocol to allow a mobile device to act as a client authenticator for a TLS1.3 channel.

Comment: This is actually a server choice; when a 1.3 handshake succeeds the server _may_ create (by derivation) one or several 'resumption' PSK(s), and _if_ it does, that PSK(s) could indeed be (transferred to and) used by a different client(s) (on a new TCP connection, to be clear), until the server deletes it/them due to timeout, cache full, or any other reason. Note the same was true previously; in 1.2 and below, the server could choose to assign a session-id _or_ ticket, and if it did so, any client with the session-id+master-secret _or_ ticket could use it.